# chain.from_iterable( repeat(load) ) in Python

Tags: python

I have the following snippet in Python.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(
   islice (
       chain.from_iterable(
             repeat(load)),
       task_id, min(task_id + step_size, last_step) )):
```

Here, load is the list created from reading an input csv file. After searching on line, I understand what are the purposes of function calls `islice` and `chain_from_iterable`. The question for me here is: why do we need to 
`repeat(load)` here? Does that mean we make copies of the list obtained from the input csv file and handle them based on the task_id or things like that? Sort of in a parallel fashion? I am pretty sure I can learn Python very well, but right now I am kindof new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repeat()` iterator makes the `load` rows look endless; you can iterate over it forever.

Presumably the actual code looks like this:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(
   islice(
       chain.from_iterable(repeat(load)),
       task_id, min(task_id + step_size, last_step)
   )):
```

e.g. the `repeat(load)` is chained, so all the data in the CSV file looks like one long sequence of rows, and when you reach the end of the CSV file you simply start at the beginning again, as if the rows in the CSV file are read from an endless loop.

The `islice()` then picks a subset of that endless loop. By making the `load` rows endless, it doesn't matter if the slice tries to take more rows from the file then are present.

Comment: I see your point. So, each cell in the long sequences is a row in the input csv file? what is the purpose of doing all this? This will be faster then?

Comment: @ntough: each cell is a *column*; if a row contains `foo,bar,baz` then each of those words is a cell.

Comment: @ntough: I don't know what kind of data you have in that file, nor what `task_id` and `step_size` or `last_step` are here, but they appear to be indices into those cells.

Comment: So, the purpose of this would be to streamlining it to make it faster, right ?

Comment: It's purpose appears to be to make the code more compact and efficient. If you tried to re-implement the same functionality without `itertools` you'd be stuck with nested loops and counters and (quite easily) off-by-n errors.

Comment: so, what are 'idx' and 'row' here?

Comment: @ntough: sorry, I mis-interpreted how `repeat()` repeats the rows in `load`; together with `chain.from_iterable()` it is indeed creating an endless chain of rows, not cells. `idx` is a number starting at `0` and `row` is a row from the CSV file, starting at row `task_id`. `enumerate()` provides `idx` here.